# ANALYZE in production code - can it hang?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to add an `analyze table_a` to my production code for better execution plans (the table often changes between a few rows and many rows, right after a query starts).

On first attempt, the analyze sometimes hung up to 5 minutes. So that was no good.

I know I can do `analyze (SKIP_LOCKED) table_a`, but the [documentation on analyze](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-analyze.html) says that it might still hang.

Is there a way to make analyze for sure not take longer than a certain time frame? Some kind of 'abort the next operation if it takes longer than X' flag?

I guess I can have a second sniping-scheduler-job running, but that's too slow, I want the analyze to take a few milliseconds or it shall give up.

Comment: where in the documentation does it say that it may hang? Can you include the quote? Because to me: `ANALYZE requires only a read lock on the target table, so it can run in parallel with other activity on the table.` sounds like it should not normally cause the freezing you describe.

Comment: `ANALYZE` only acquires a read lock. So what's blocking it? `TRUNCATE`? How many is "many rows"?

Comment: the documentation says "Note that even with this option, ANALYZE may still block when opening the relation's indexes or when acquiring sample rows from partitions, table inheritance children, and some types of foreign tables"

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I did not check where it hangs (albeit I agree that it would be very interesting) - but the fact that it potentially might hang was enough for me to rule out using it in production code when fast responses are needed. Many rows for this table means about 200.000, so not huge.

Comment: What about the configuration of auto analyze? You can set this on server level, but also table level. It's up to you. Personally I would not try to implement a replacement for that.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter. For the lock ANALYZE takes and what it can conflict with see [Explicit Locking](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html): *https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html Conflicts with the SHARE UPDATE EXCLUSIVE, SHARE, SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE, EXCLUSIVE, and ACCESS EXCLUSIVE lock modes. This mode protects a table against concurrent schema changes and VACUUM runs. ...*

Comment: @FrankHeikens yes, I would prefer to solve the bad stats problem via autovacuum alone. But there are several processes writing/reading to/from this table all at the same time. The table is going from a few rows to 200k rows quickly back and forth. There is no way that autovacuum can keep up with that. I was curious whether there is a production-safe (in terms of providing a guaranteed max. hang of x ms) way to have `analyze` in the code. That might not be the case. I have now opted to split the problematic query into 2 parts via a temp table, but I was curious about the manual `analyze` option